# CFGMap Google map API V3 always center map on long/lat

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm using CFGMap solution to place markers on a google map (API V3) but I want the map to always be centered on a certain long/latitude. Right now it seems to center on the last marker placed on the map so if the majority are where I want the long/lat centered then one random marker will take view miles away.

Any help on this is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

CFGMap is infuriating for it's lack of documentation. I don't use it myself; I only tried to track down something that might help you. On the face of it, it appears only to take a tiny subset of the full API functionality and doesn't offer much else.

From what I can glean from the [testmap.js](http://examples.cutterscrossing.com/CFGMap/scripts/testmap.js) found [here](http://www.cutterscrossing.com/index.cfm/CFGMap), it appears that you can only center the map on an existing marker in your locations array (see line 616 of the [github file](https://github.com/cutterbl/CFGMap/blob/master/scripts/gMap.js)).

```
_cfGMapObj.resetCenterToLoc(index);
```

So, for example, in the source of the [example](http://examples.cutterscrossing.com/cfgmap/) is the line:

```
_cfGMapObj.resetCenterToLoc($('#locID','#printLink').val());
```

which grabs the number from the value of the current option in the `select` at the top of the page.

**Now**, if you chose instead to knock CFGMap on the head you could employ the Map API fully and set the center of the map using the `setCenter` method of the API.:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
```

e.g.

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(57.4419, -121.1419));
```

which in my mind is much easier. Plus, if you decided to do this, there are tons more articles on the API on StackOverflow than there are on CFGMap. YMMV.

Comment: I concur with Andy.  I can't really see the point of using either CFMap or CFGMap; the API JS is pretty straightforward, unless you're keen on always using CF as an interface to your javascript, with limited functionality as a result